# XSLT Exact path

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing an xml to json parser using XSLT.

Here is my xml:

```
<Item>
 <ChildItems>
  <Item>
    <Id>child-1</Id> 
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Id>child-2</Id> 
  </Item> 
 </ChildItems>
 <Id>main-1</Id>
</Item>
```

I try to get the Id of the main element(main-1), but I get the Id of the first ChildItem (child-1).

```
      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  
                      xmlns:custom="custom:v1:interop" version="1.0"> 

     ...

     "Id": "<xsl:value-of select="//custom:Item/custom:Id" />"

     ...
```

I can't change the XML so please don't suggest this as solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you post a **complete** example that would enable us to reproduce your issue (including an XML that matches the XSLT in terms of namespaces). Most importantly: where you are (in what context) when you call this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have posted the full XML where the outer `Item` is the root element then the path `/Item/Id` would select the `Id` child element of the `Item` root element.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your XSL code and wrote absolute XPATH for Id and relative XPATH starting at Item.
I use your namespace custom, assuming the you need it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:custom="custom:v1:interop" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="myId" select="custom:Item/custom:Id"/>
    <xsl:template match="custom:Item">
    <root>
    using relative XPATH: <xsl:value-of select="custom:Id"/>
    using absolute XPATH:  <xsl:value-of select="$myId"/>
    </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```